# I can't execute .bin file in Ubuntu Bash Terminal in Windows 10

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I've a problem. I use Ubuntu for Windows 10 in Terminal (from Microsoft Store, bash), but I can't execute .bin file. (WSL)

[image]

I specify my program is without GUI, it's just a terminal's apps (and it's work perfectly in Virtual Linux Machine)

More information about my file and my os:[image]

Can you help me please?

Comment: Guessing you are running on a 64bit system without the 32bit sublayer. Guessing that the binary is too old to run. Copy it to local disk then try and run it.

Comment: The file is a root me challenge(2011) https://www.root-me.org/fr/Challenges/Cracking/ELF-x86-Basique  (my ubuntu os is 64 bits) and "local disk" I don't understand... You talk about the c disk / folder? Because I try and... He didn't work.

Comment: Your os may be 64bit, but that exe is 32bit. You need the 32bit sublayer. That disk is not truly local to the ubuntu os as I assume it is dual boot. Copy it and retry, although it will probably still fail.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: So, I tried to copy one more time and he didn't work. So I try to install "the 32bit sublayer". I execute this 2 commands sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update, and...the terminal show me an error: Errors were encountered while processing:
 xwayland.

Comment: I try with WSL Kali linux (to install the package) I've no error, but my program does not want to start

Comment: AFAIK WSL1 does not support 32-bit ELF binaries. See [Run 32-bit application on Ubuntu on Windows subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1407730/run-32-bit-application-on-ubuntu-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux)